# Error: compiled without dbus support?

Tags: build

I am running Emacs 24.5.1 (compiled) and Spacemacs v.0.105.4 on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I try to use the spotify layer I get the following error:
peculiar error: "Emacs not compiled with dbus support".

How do I fix it?

Comment: It looks like your version did not get compiled with dbus support.  Not sure what version is in the Ubuntu repositories, but if you pulled it from there and are getting this message, you may need to compile from source instead with the dbus option enabled (see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Installing-Emacs.html) and [Xah Lee's page](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/building_emacs_from_git_repository.html) for information on doing so).

Comment: And by the way, your Ubuntu install is nearly 4-years old.  You may want to think about upgrading.

Comment: company policy, need to work on this platform .

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution:
I was missing the package libdbus-1-dev. After ./configure && make dbus support was automatically added. So basically follow:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```